# HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API - No suggestion for an existing location

Tags: here-api, geo

I have an issue with a location I need to find with HERE API : *194 avenue de la Gare Sud de France, 34970 Lattes*

I'm not able to find it.

As it's an existing, could you please advice on what I need to do to fix this issue?

I'm using the Geocoder Autocomplete API and Here is my request :

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json
?apiKey={MYAPIKEY}
&query=194%20avenue%20de%20la%20Gare%20Sud%20de%20France%2034970%20Lattes
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestion in response :

```
{
    "suggestions": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the query parameter, you can't have spaces on it. Try to use + sign instead.

`https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json ?apiKey={MYAPIKEY} &query=194+avenue+de+la+Gare+Sud+de+France+34970+Lattes`